# How to pass an argument with line breaks in a shell to an ant script

Tags: shell, jenkins, ant

I like to execute an ant task in a shell in jenkins with 2 arguments while arg1 is a string with line breaks.

```
arg1=test1; 
test2; 
test3

arg2=nothing_new;
```

Usually I use "" if there are line breaks in a string but this does not work:

```
ant target1 -Dparam1="$arg1" -Dparam2=$arg2 
Result:
param1=test1
param2=test2
```

If i do not use "" the string after the first line break will be ignored:

```
ant target1 -Dparam1=$arg1 -Dparam2=$arg2 
Result:
param1=test1
param2=nothing_new
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is what you need:

```
arg1='test1; 
test2; 
test3'

arg2='nothing_new;'

ant target1 -Dparam1="$arg1" -Dparam2="$arg2"
```

I've put single quotes around both your string literals and double quotes around the variables, so the whitespace is preserved in both places.

The single quotes are needed around the multi-line variable declaration, otherwise you'd be setting `arg1=test1;` and then executing two commands `test2` and `test3`.

You could use double quotes everywhere but personally I prefer to make it clear whether you expect parameter expansion to occur (double quotes) or not (single quotes).